# Regex to match an exact word which can only have spaces etc in front or after it

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to figure out a regex that will match a certain word, where the word cannot be a part of any other "word".

**So this word that I am trying to match can only have spaces, tabs or linebreaks in front or after it.**

I have tried the following:

```
s\sWORD$
s\sWORD\s
^WORD\s
```

Comment: [Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Comment: spaces before and after the word:
\sword\s

Comment: I'll be using Pattern in Java for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this word that I am trying to match can only have spaces, tabs or linebreaks in front or after it.

One of these regex patterns should work for you:

```
(?<=\s|^)WORD(?=\s|$)
(?<!\S|^)WORD(?!\S)
```

First one means `WORD` must be preceded by whitespace or line start and it must be followed by whitespace or line end.

Second one means `WORD` must NOT be preceded by non-whitespace and it must NOT be followed by a non-whitespace.

**Java examples:**

```
"WORD abc".matches(".*?(?<=\\s|^)WORD(?=\\s|$).*"); // true

"WORD".matches(".*?(?<=\\s|^)WORD(?=\\s|$).*"); // true

"WORD-abc".matches(".*?(?<=\\s|^)WORD(?=\\s|$).*"); // false

"some-WORD".matches(".*?(?<=\\s|^)WORD(?=\\s|$).*"); // false
```

Comment: Actually I also didn't post an answer for a long time thinking all OP needs is word boundary. But then I re-read question and found this quoted line **this word that I am trying to match can only have spaces, tabs or linebreaks in front or after it.** and with that I concluded that `WORD-abc` should not match as the case with `\b`. Hence the need of look-arounds to make sure word is only surrounded by space or start/end anchors.

Comment: Ok, then `\b` would not work. Good answer!